# Can I use API exposed in an open source project (MIT License) in a commercial software?

Tags: mit, copyright, github, api

I wanted to use an api that is exposed in an open source project under MIT License.There's no restrictions mentioned for the use of api anywhere in the License neither it says that we can use the api So, Is it legal to use that api in my commercial Software?

Comment: The MIT license text itself already answers what you may do better than anyone here could answer you: *Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software*.
Is there something about the permission statement that is not clear that you need specific help on?

Comment: What do you mean by "use an api that is exposed in an open source project under MIT License"? Do you want to provide an alternative implementation of the api, or do you want to use that library in your project, or something else?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Explained: There's an open source project on github and it uses an api to communicate with its server.The software works on the results received from the server.Although the project is open source with MIT License , I just wanted to know that if it is legal to use that api to communicate with their server in my commercial software.

Comment: @Brandin 
Suppose..There a project named X that used www.example.com to communicate with its server. 
Now project X is open source but is it legal to make calls using www.example.com in my own commercial software?

Comment: @ShubhamSoni There are two separate questions to consider. Copying the source code (MIT licensed, in this case) and actually using a remote service. Normally using a remote service is governed by so called Terms of Service. You would need to know what the TOS are for the service you are using. Or else create your *own* version of www.example.com that can be used under any terms you choose.

Comment: @Brandin The website says that: All the Content  is under the Creative Commons License.

Comment: The Creative Commons license is about copying content, not about using a web site's API. If there are no Terms of Service mentioned for an API, but you want to know if it's legal to use it anyway (e.g. the API is documented), that might be an interesting question but I'm not sure if it's exactly an open source question. Right now your question is mixing up other things though, like MIT licensed source code and Creative Commons content, so as is you won't get an answer to your "is it OK to use the API of a remote server in the absence of a Terms of Service saying that I may do so" question.